# Any way to push files onto android phones?

Tags: file-transfer

There is any way to push files from a computer to an Android phone? Maybe to its SD card. It may work like [Android Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/), but the opposite way (PC to phone), as in Chrome-to-phone.

I looked some apps like FTP servers, web servers, but I would like something more close to "right click on file, push" than to "connect to server using a ftp client or browser, drag  or select file, and send".

Comment: Are you trying to do it over a network, or is mounting the external storage and using it as a mass storage device sufficient? That's drag and drop, and I'd wager 99% of Android devices (if not all of them) support it in some form or another. Windows even has a baked in Right Click->"Send To.." functionality if you're using that.

Comment: We prefer questions that ask about a specific problem, rather than asking for a specific app that is perceived to fix the problem. It is entirely possible that there is a non-app solution and it makes the question more universal. Future readers might have the same problem, after all.

Comment: Al Everett, done.

Answer (score 6):

[Dropbox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android) and [Ubuntu One](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files) has Android client.

FoxToPhone has a hidden feature to [push arbitrary file](http://www.foxtophone.com/2010/08/whats-the-easter-egg-in-1-1/) from Firefox to your phone.

Answer (score 3):

[GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/) is able to send, browse and receive files from your android phone via XMPP (gTalk). It's also a remote SMS notifier and has various other features.

Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved in GTalkSMS. GTalkSMS is an open source GPL licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PushBullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)

This is the best way I found to do it. It has a web interface, a chrome extension and a firefox extension. It lets you push files, notes, lists, urls and addresses. It's only limitation is filesize under 10mb.

Answer (score 1):

In CyanogenMod at least, plugging a phone into your computer will make it offer to turn on USB mass storage, which exposes the SD card as writable. That's about as "drag and drop" as one can get.

Post specifics on your phone if you don't get this prompt.

Opinion: with data plans no longer being unlimited in the US, why not use a cable?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app called Browser to Phone. My app is similar to chrometophone, but it allows you to actually download the links to your phone:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wiirecords.chrometophone

Comment: This does look fairly relevant, but please take a look at the FAQ section on [self promotion](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

Awesome Drop can be used to accomplish this for smaller files. Install the app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dashwire.drop on your computer, open their site, enter the pairing code and drop files into the browser. It is pretty slick and easy to use.

I use Dropbox for most of my needs, it doesn't sync to my phone, but works for having files I want, close at hand.

Answer (score 0):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) allows you to push files to your Android device over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

Using XMPP as transport, the "desktop app" can be every XMPP Client. Which is one of the big advantages of MAXS, as it does not need a dedicated desktop app. Although there may be one in the future.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>